# WebView doesn't seem to get destroyed after leaving activity?

Tags: android

I've got an activity with a webview. Looks like the webview does not get destroyed along with the activity. To demonstrate, I've created an html page which runs a timer that loads an image resource every few seconds. The script continues executing after the activity is destroyed:

```
public class MyWebViewActivity extends Activity {
  private WebView mWebView;

  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.the_layout);

    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new EmbeddedWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("test url");
  }

  private class EmbeddedWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);

        if (Config.DEBUG) { Log.v(TAG, "onLoadResource(): " + url); }
    }
  }
}
```

So the above just prints a log statement whenever onLoadResource() is called. Here's the javascript in the test html page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function load() {
        setInterval("doit()", 3000);
      }

      function doit() {
        Image1 = new Image(150, 20);
        Image1.src = "abc_" + Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + ".png";
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
  </body>
</html>
```

The above just creates an image resource on the timer interval to trigger the onLoadResource() method in EmbeddedWebViewClient().

So yeah I can see in LogCat that the messages keep printing after leaving the activity. Do we have to shut down the WebView somehow? Maybe this is the issue described here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9375

if it's a known issue should it have been documented in the api docs?

Note: Running this on android 2.3.4, Nexus S.

Thanks

Comment: my webview can play audio after onDestroy been called, it astonishing  that google have not fixed this,

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked for me:

In MyActivity.java file, I added:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    webview.destroy();
    webview = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the pauseTimers() and resumeTimers() calls. If you add this to your activity I think it'll start doing what you expect:

```
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if (mWebView != null) {
      mWebView.resumeTimers();
  }
}

public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  if (mWebView != null) {
      mWebView.pauseTimers();
  }
}
```

The logcat messages stop when you swap away from the app and start back up when you return.

Comment: Good to know, still worried though about the implications of not calling pauseTimers() - so if you don't call that method, then your activity leaks the entire webview? The documentation doesn't bring this to our attention, it seems like a bug in the sdk? When the parent activity is finished, one would think that the webview is automatically gc'd (all timers shut down etc)

Comment: It's not "finished" however, unless you call finish() on the Activity. If you started a thread of you own when you created the Activity it wouldn't stop when your activity stopped either, you would have to manage it yourself. Same thing, though it's a bit more abstracted here.

Comment: I tried this but the timers still do not stop - I can see their messages printed to logcat.

Comment: I just tied it out again on a 2.2 emulator session. Bring up the view, watch resource messages load. Hit the home button, messages stop. Long press on home and swap back to app, messages start again. Not much more to it.

Answer (score 1):

If the activity will not be resumed, you can also call mWebView.stopLoading().

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with WebView but are you sure your activity is really getting destroyed? 
Try calling

```
this.finish()
```

when you want it to exit.
If that still doesn't work, then you want to gain control over what happens when the activity is about to die:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
//    make a call to your script, tell it to end
}
```

Of course, if you want your script to stop without completely destroying your activity, you can override onPause() or onStop()

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes but the user can finish the activity by hitting the back key. In that case we rely on the framework to tear everything down. The WebView should be stopping all scripts and have its memory freed. This seems like a pretty big problem (if it is indeed happening as I described above)

Answer (score 0):

It seems not.

android develop doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) says

> The standard behavior for an Activity is to be destroyed and recreated when the device orientation or any other configuration changes. This will cause the WebView to reload the current page.

So, I think there is no need to destroy the webview when you leave the activity. Just listen some event.